# aws - how to pass stage variables in API Gateway to Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

(Ruby)

I have an APIGateway and a lambda function.
I can define environment variables in lambda and see them.
How do I access the API Gateway variables inside the lambda function ?
I'm thinking they are in the event hash but not sure how to put them there if so.

#### Lambda

### [image]

#### API Gateway

### [image]

#### Cloud Watch Logs

[image]

Comment: `In the root resource, create a new GET method. In Integration type for the new method, choose Lambda Function, then select your Lambda Region, and type ${stageVariables.lbfunc} in the Lambda Function field. This tells API Gateway to read the value for this field from a stage variable at runtime` https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/ did you do that?